# How to load saved google app script file in script editor?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

So..I know this sounds very stupid, but I have saved my script file on the drive and when I went to my editor and did file -> open.., I was taken to my drive and I was able to find the script file I previously saved. However I could only download it as a json file but couldn't reopen it in my google script editor. Please help!

Comment: When I do "open with >" in my drive, it says no application available

Comment: You can't open a Apps Script JSON file directly from the Apps Script code editor.  In your Google Drive, you can double click a JSON file, and then choose to open it with Apps Script.  If you downloaded the Apps Script file to your local drive (probably hard drive), then you would need to click the big red "New" button in Drive, and then choose "File Upload" to upload the JSON file from your computer drive to Google Drive.  Downloading the Apps Script file as JSON is very good to do as a backup, but other than that, you should just use the regular Apps Script file in your Drive.

Comment: ohhh got it, not too intuitive but finally. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to open stand alone projects of Google Apps Scripts.

NOTE: The [Issue 5963:  Cannot open standalone Google App Scripts in Drive](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=5963) could be fixed now.

If the preview is shown,

1. Go to http://drive.google.com
2. Navigate or search for project file
3. Double clic. At this time the file preview will open.
4. Click the Open in a new window button in the top right corner.

[image: Preview of a Script file in Google Drive]

Answer (score -1):

I can confirm that I am having this issue as well. I have several prebuilt app scripts saved to my google drive. They were all built with the online script editor. Usually I'd open up my drive (online) and just double click a script to open it. Now nothing happens. Not even open with shows an option to open the file with app script.

Might be a Google wide issue. I'll post updates when fixed or if I find a Google support link

**Update:**

As posted by the user below, the bug was posted [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=5963) in Google support forum. Make sure to visit it to add your two cents and also star the issue so we can get a quicker resolution.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12106001)

Comment: Will be updating results, so it'll become the answer. Just needed to let the guy know that he wasn't alone.

Comment: There are comments for that.